# httpd.service active failed

Tags: apache, service, server

Can someone help me what's wrong?
I tried to install let's encrypt
but when I do "status httpd.service" this error occur

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-05-07 10:32:15 CST; 5min ago
  Docs: man:httpd(8)
        man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 21861 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 21859 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 21859 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile httpd[21859]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.24.141.99. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile httpd[21859]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile httpd[21859]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile httpd[21859]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile kill[21861]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: May 07 10:32:15 JobSmile httpd[21859]: (`98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` explains the problem. Your port number 80 seems to be in use...

Comment: @RomeoSierra What should I do? I don't really understand about this. Can you help? Of course port 80 is in use. I think. Since the server host a website.

Comment: Two options. Either find out which process is holding onto the port (`netstat -nlp | grep 80`) and terminate it(`sudo kill -9 <pid>`), which is believe is impossible in your case. Or else, configure apache to run in a different port. How to do it? Just google it and you will find a thousand+ instructional websites...

Comment: @RomeoSierra Thank I will try

Comment: @RomeoSierra I think I have 2 httpd installed in my system. i found out that my website used different place of httpd.conf than this. What should I do?

Comment: Can you see more than one when you run `netstat -nlp | grep apache`?